# nginx + php-fpm macos pending request longer 60s

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

the problem is that all requests are almost always suspended for more than a minute, and they give out 504 Gateway Time-out, Mac os Ventura 13.6 (22G120), I tried to pick nginx and php fpm settings, there is nothing in the logs to understand what the problem is, it is written in error.log nginx - 2023/12/26 06:08:28 [error] 16#16: *5 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.65.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app/queues-new/clients-list?page=1&count=100 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock", host: "localhost:10001", who has ever encountered such a problem?

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name localhost;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/project/back/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
      include fastcgi_params;
      try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

server {
    listen *:443;
    server_name localhost;

    # SSL SETTINGS START #
    ssl_certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/server.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/ssl/private/server.key";
    ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    # END SSL SETTINGS #

    # GZIP SETTINGS START #
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
    # END GZIP SETTINGS #

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/project/back/public;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
      include fastcgi_params;
      try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1.0'

services:
  robot_web_back:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: robot_web
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=CPLDOCKER"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./back/
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/project/back/
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/project/back/
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "10001:80"
      - "10444:443"
      - "8800:8800"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.6
    container_name: robot_web_postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: portal
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: robot_web_redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - cache:/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  cache:
    driver: local
```

DockerFile

```
# First, We need an Operating System for our docker. We choose alpine.
FROM alpine:3.15.2

# Next, Update Alpine OS
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

# Next, we need to install utilities inside alpine, we can achieve this by type RUN then, the alpine command.
# Install apline utilities and php depedencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    php7 \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-gd \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-curl \
    php7-bcmath \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-intl \
    php7-json \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-mysqlnd \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-phar \
    php7-posix \
    php7-session \
    php7-soap \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zip \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-redis \
    php7-xdebug \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libltdl \
    mc \
    php7-dom \
    openrc

RUN apk add --no-cache php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev make && pecl install redis

# Next, Install nginx on alpine official guide in nginx official site. I just copied and paste what's on the site guide for installing nginx on alpine.
# https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/
RUN apk add openssl curl ca-certificates

# To set up the apk repository for stable nginx packages, run the command:
RUN printf "%s%s%s\n" \
"http://nginx.org/packages/alpine/v" \
`egrep -o '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' /etc/alpine-release` \
"/main" \
| tee -a /etc/apk/repositories

# Import an official nginx signing key so apk could verify the packages authenticity. Fetch the key:
RUN curl -o /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.rsa.pub

# Verify that the downloaded file contains the proper key:
RUN openssl rsa -pubin -in /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub -text -noout

# Move the key to apk trusted keys storage
RUN mv /tmp/nginx_signing.rsa.pub /etc/apk/keys/

# Now, install nginx
RUN apk add nginx
RUN touch /var/run/php-fpm.sock

RUN sed -i 's#127.0.0.1:9000#/var/run/php-fpm.sock#g' /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf

# Install PHP Composer, If you use composer, you can uncomment this one.
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

#Xdebug
COPY docker/xdebug.ini /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini

# copy project file to nginx inside docker.
COPY ./back /usr/share/nginx/html/project/back

# Copy default config and paste it into nginx config path inside docker.
COPY ./nginx-configs/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# SSL
COPY docker/certs/server.pem /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem
COPY docker/certs/server.key /etc/ssl/private/server.key
RUN chmod 0600 /etc/ssl/private/server.key
RUN chmod 0600 /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem

# Expose port to be visible outside the container.
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

# Execute startup command.
# Start php-fpm8 and nginx through bash terminal.
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "php-fpm7 && chmod 777 /run/php-fpm.sock && chmod 755 /usr/share/nginx/html/* && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# 127.0.0.1:8081 robot-front.ru
# 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
# 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I tried to configure nginx+php-fpm, but I keep getting pending for more than 60 seconds, I tried poking around in the nginx conf settings, but I still get pending for more than one minute, I'm not sure but I'm starting to think if it's mac os

Comment: "upstream timed out" would suggest that your php application is not available (it's not available to nginx which proxies the requests to php). Not sure how to debug php, but can you check for example if "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock" is alive?